# How can we set different images on different image view by clicking different button from camera and gallery?

Tags: android

I have a four button which select image from gallery it will display on `Imageview` .
 But the problem is that when I select one image it fills the same image in the four `Imageview`.

Please kindly solve my problem,I will be grateful to you.

code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterServiceProvider extends Activity {

    private Bitmap docimg,dlimage,passportdoc,textcertificate;
    String iddd;
    ImageView imageView;

    private String userid;
    String url;

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    byte[] bitmapdata;

    ImageView eimage;

    String ba1,setgender;

//  
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE2 = 3;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE3 = 4;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE4= 5;


    private static final int PICK_Camera_IMAGE = 2;
    private ImageView imgView;
    private Button upload,cancel;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    Uri imageUri;
    Spinner spinner1;
    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();



    /////

    TextView regds,doccomp,docoftext,doudl,updlss,updpasso,select;

    Button submit;
    Typeface type;

    CheckBox check;

    EditText uname,emailid,password,confpass,companyname,companyreg,valdate,ownerdetail,fname,surname,nationality,dlno,psidno,contactno,familymemberphno,mobno,addcon;

    Spinner companytype,gender;

    ImageView companydoc,taxcertificate,uploaddl,passport;

    String suname,semailid,spassword,sconfpass,scompanyname,scompanyreg,svaldate,sownerdetail,sfname,ssurname,snationality,sdlno,spsidno,scontactno,sfamilymemberphno,smobno,saddcon;
    String scompanytype,sgender;

     Button codoc,texcef,updl,updlpassport;
     InputStream iss;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo;
        Bitmap bitmapOrg;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao ;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.servicregdactivity);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  


        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"segoeui.ttf");
        regds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.regds);
        regds.setText("Service Provider Registeration");
        regds.setTextSize(14);
        regds.setTypeface( type);

        doccomp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.doccomp);
        doccomp.setText("Upload your Company Doc.");
        doccomp.setTextSize(14);
        doccomp.setTypeface( type);

        docoftext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.docoftext);
        docoftext.setText("Upload your TextDocument.");
        docoftext.setTextSize(14);
        docoftext.setTypeface( type);

        doudl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.doudl);
        doudl.setText("Do you have DL ?");
        doudl.setTextSize(14);
        doudl.setTypeface( type);

        updlss = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updlss);
        updlss.setText("Upload your  DL here.");
        updlss.setTextSize(14);
        updlss.setTypeface( type);

        updpasso  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updpasso);
        updpasso.setText("Upload your Passport here.");
        updpasso.setTextSize(14);
        updpasso.setTypeface( type);

        select  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.select);
        select.setText("Select The Term And Condition.");
        select.setTextSize(12);
        select.setTypeface( type);

        check =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setText("Register");
        submit.setTextSize(16);
        submit.setTypeface( type);

        uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        emailid  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        confpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confpass);
        companyname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.companyname);
        companyreg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.companyreg);
        valdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.valdate);
        ownerdetail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ownerdetail);
        fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        surname  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.surname);
        nationality = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nationality);
        dlno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dlno);
        contactno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contactno);
        familymemberphno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.familymemberphno);
        mobno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobno);
        addcon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addcon);
        psidno  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passportno);


        check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                  if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                      check.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_active) ;

                  } else {
                      check.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_deactive) ;

                  }
              }
          });

        TextView cross = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cross);
        cross.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                finish();
            }
        });


        //spinner data 
        companytype = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.companytype);
        gender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gender);


        //System.gc();
                String[] gendertype= new String[]{"Gender Type","Male","Female"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.listrow, gendertype);
                gender.setAdapter(adapter);

                gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int pos, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                sgender = gender.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                                //gender.setText(setgender);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });

                String[] companyname= new String[]{"Select Company","Electrical","Plumber"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.listrow, companyname);
                companytype.setAdapter(adapters);

                companytype.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int pos, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                scompanytype = companytype.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                                //gender.setText(setgender);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });



        // imageview  data

        companydoc = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.companydoc);
        taxcertificate = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.taxcertificate);
        uploaddl = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.uploaddl);
        passport = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.passport);

        codoc  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.codoc);
        texcef  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.texcef);
        updl  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updl);
        updlpassport  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updlpassport);

        codoc.setText("Upload");
        codoc.setTextSize(16);
        codoc.setTypeface( type);

        texcef.setText("Upload");
        texcef.setTextSize(16);
        texcef.setTypeface( type);

        updl.setText("Upload");
        updl.setTextSize(16);
        updl.setTypeface( type);

        updlpassport.setText("Upload");
        updlpassport.setTextSize(16);
        updlpassport.setTypeface( type);




        codoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent gintent = new Intent();
                    gintent.setType("image/*");
                    gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(gintent, "Select Picture"),
                    PICK_IMAGE);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
        });

        texcef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent gintent = new Intent();
                    gintent.setType("image/*");
                    gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(gintent, "Select Picture"),
                    PICK_IMAGE2);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
        });

        updl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent gintent = new Intent();
                    gintent.setType("image/*");
                    gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(gintent, "Select Picture"),
                    PICK_IMAGE3);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
        });

        updlpassport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent gintent = new Intent();
                    gintent.setType("image/*");
                    gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(gintent, "Select Picture"),
                    PICK_IMAGE4);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
        });



        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {




                /*if (bitmap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterServiceProvider.this, "Uploading Your Data",
                            "Please wait...", true);
                    new ImageGalleryTask().execute();

                }*/
                new serviceProviderRegistration().execute();    
            }
        });


        }
    }


    private class serviceProviderRegistration extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterServiceProvider.this);
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try 
                {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ServiceProviderRegistration.....");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                /*  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    */
                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();



                    suname = uname.getText().toString();
                    semailid = emailid.getText().toString();
                    spassword = password.getText().toString();
                    sconfpass = confpass.getText().toString();
                    scompanyname = companyname.getText().toString();
                    scompanyreg = companyreg.getText().toString();
                    svaldate = valdate.getText().toString();
                    sownerdetail = ownerdetail.getText().toString();
                    sfname = fname.getText().toString();
                    ssurname = surname.getText().toString();
                    snationality = nationality.getText().toString();
                    sdlno = dlno.getText().toString();
                    spsidno = psidno.getText().toString();
                    scontactno = contactno.getText().toString();
                    sfamilymemberphno = familymemberphno.getText().toString();
                    smobno = mobno.getText().toString();
                    saddcon = addcon.getText().toString(); 

                    scompanytype = companytype.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    sgender  = gender.getSelectedItem().toString();

                System.out.println("print all datas.........."+suname);    

                    suname.replace("" ,"%20");
                    semailid.replace("" ,"%20");
                    spassword.replace("" ,"%20");
                    sconfpass.replace("" ,"%20");
                    scompanyname.replace("" ,"%20");
                    scompanyreg.replace("" ,"%20");
                    svaldate.replace("" ,"%20");
                    sownerdetail.replace("" ,"%20");
                    sfname.replace("" ,"%20");
                    ssurname.replace("" ,"%20");
                    snationality.replace("" ,"%20");
                    sdlno.replace("" ,"%20");
                    spsidno.replace("" ,"%20");
                    scontactno.replace("" ,"%20");
                    sfamilymemberphno.replace("" ,"%20");
                    smobno.replace("" ,"%20");
                    saddcon.replace("" ,"%20");
                    scompanytype.replace("" ,"%20");
                    sgender.replace("" ,"%20");



                    bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bfo.inSampleSize = 32;

                    //bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + customImage, bfo);
                      bfo.inScaled = true;
                      bfo.inPurgeable = true;

                    bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();




                    docimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bao);
                    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                    int baa = (ba.length)/1024;

                     dlimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bao);
                        byte [] baaa = bao.toByteArray();
                        int baas = (baaa.length)/1024;

                        passportdoc.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bao);
                            byte [] baaap = bao.toByteArray();
                            int baasp = (baaap.length)/1024;

                            textcertificate.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bao);
                                byte [] baaat = bao.toByteArray();
                                int baast = (baaat.length)/1024;

                    System.out.println("size of image ....."+baa);
                    //String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
                    System.out.println(" imagedata................"+baa);



                    String image_str_companydoc = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                    String image_str_taxcertificate = Base64.encodeBytes(baaat);

                String image_str_uploaddl = Base64.encodeBytes(baaa);
                String image_str_passport = Base64.encodeBytes(baaap);


                    System.out.println("size of image1 ................."+image_str_companydoc);
                    System.out.println("size of image2 ................."+image_str_taxcertificate);
                    System.out.println("size of image3 ................."+image_str_uploaddl);
                    System.out.println("size of image4 ................."+image_str_passport);

                    job.put("method","service_provider_signup");


                    job.put("username",suname);
                    job.put("email",semailid);
                    job.put("password",spassword);
                    job.put("company_type",sconfpass);
                    job.put("company_name",scompanyname);
                    job.put("company_registration",scompanyreg);
                    job.put("tax_validation",svaldate);
                    job.put("owner_details",sownerdetail);
                    job.put("first_name",sfname);
                    job.put("last_name",ssurname);

                    job.put("gender",sgender);
                    job.put("nationality",snationality);
                    job.put("id_pass_number",spsidno);
                    job.put("driving_lic",sdlno);
                    job.put("contact_no",scontactno);
                    job.put("other_details",sfamilymemberphno);
                    job.put("terms_cond","1");
                    job.put("mobile",smobno);
                    job.put("address_phone",saddcon);

                    job.put("company_doc",image_str_companydoc);
                    job.put("tax_certificate_doc",image_str_taxcertificate);
                    job.put("driver_lic_doc",image_str_uploaddl);
                    job.put("pass_id_doc",image_str_passport);




                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());

                    System.out.println("send items print here..............."+se);


                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sw-sol-world.com/clients/planb/webservice.php");

                    httppost.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    System.out.println("response "+data);

                    String call;
                    call = data;

                    System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                    {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterServiceProvider.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Service Provider Registration!!!");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) 
                            {
                                pDialog.dismiss();


                                dialog.dismiss();

                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterServiceProvider.this,LoginScreen.class));

                            }
                        });
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //params[0]="0";

                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterServiceProvider.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
        {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
               MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
               inflater.inflate(R.menu.splash_screen, menu);
               return true;
      }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.camera:
                //define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity
                String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
                //create parameters for Intent with filename
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image captured by camera");
                //imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                //create new Intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_Camera_IMAGE);
                return true;

            case R.id.gallery:
                try {
                Intent gintent = new Intent();
                gintent.setType("image/*");
                gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(gintent, "Select Picture"),
                PICK_IMAGE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
                return true;
       }
        return false;
   }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = null;
        String filePath = null;
        switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_IMAGE:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    }
                    break;

                case PICK_Camera_IMAGE:
                     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        //use imageUri here to access the image
                        selectedImageUri = imageUri;
                        /*Bitmap mPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mPic, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())));*/
                    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                     break;
            }

            if(selectedImageUri != null){
                    try {
                        // OI FILE Manager
                        String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                        // MEDIA GALLERY
                        String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                        if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                            filePath = selectedImagePath;
                        } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                            filePath = filemanagerstring;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                        }

                        if (filePath != null) {
                            decodeFile(filePath);
                        } else {
                            bitmap = null;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
            }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

//          int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
//          String picturePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
//          String picturePaths = cursor.getString(column_index);
//          String picturePathd = cursor.getString(column_index);
//          String picturePathh = cursor.getString(column_index);
//          
//          cursor.close();
//          
//          
//          companydoc.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
//          taxcertificate.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePaths));
//          uploaddl.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePathd));
//          passport.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePathh));
//          
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;

        docimg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
        textcertificate = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
        dlimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
        passportdoc = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

        companydoc.setImageBitmap(docimg);
        taxcertificate.setImageBitmap(textcertificate);
        uploaddl.setImageBitmap(dlimage);
        passport.setImageBitmap(passportdoc);


    }

}
```

Comment: Show me the code, please

Comment: @user3492898 post your code here. It seems you are referring same image in all four imageviews.

Comment: I have send the code please rectify and post